# Show data from another table in place of foreign value in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datagridview

I am using C# [C sharp] and sql server for development of desktop application.
I have three tables:

1. **tblSbjEmp**
       sID
       eID
2. **tblSbj**
   sID
   SubjectName
3. **tblEmp**
   eID
   EmployeeName

I want to show **tblSbjEmp** in Datagridview.
I have replaced combobox hidding **eID** in datagridview very easily but my problem is that **I want SubjectName (not combobox) in place of sID in the grid which must be readonly**

```
    public DataSet getDS(String strTableName, String strQuery)
    {
        myCon = new SqlConnection("connection string");
        try
        {
            DS = new DataSet();
            DA = new SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, myCon);
            SqlCommandBuilder cmdBldr = new SqlCommandBuilder(DA);
            DA.Fill(DS, strTableName);
            return DS;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "-----" + ex.ToString());
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            return DS;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                myCon.Close();
        }

    }


ds = SObj.getDS("tblSbjEmp", "Select * from tblSbjEmp");

//Lecturer Combobox
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Employee = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
Employee.HeaderText = "Lecturer";
Employee.Name = "Employee";
Employee.MaxDropDownItems = 4;
Employee.Visible = true;
Employee.Width = 150;
Employee.DataSource = clsSettings.getAllRecords("Select eID, EmployeeName from tblEmp");

Employee.DataPropertyName = "eID";
Employee.ValueMember = "eID";
Employee.DisplayMember = "EmployeeName";

dgvLecturer.Columns.Add(Employee);
```

In combobox we can set DatapropertyName, ValueMember & DisplayMember and select datasource of combox but how can i get **SubjectName** (fixed value) in place of sID. but when i have to update the table i have to update sID the following is the update command i use.
    SObj.DA.Update(ds, "tblSbjCrs"); **Query** is not update-able through this method, so i have used single table behind grid.

Comment: Are you inserting the content in the tbl's from a database??

Comment: Yes, i want to update table **tblSbjEmp** only no Add, no Delete

Comment: Need to modify your select query. Share it so it could be changed accordingly.

Comment: Other thing you can do is to use subject name (if it is unique) instead of sID means use only tblSbjEmp and leave using tbSbj

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, one thing vimp, while asking question on stackoverflow you must share what you have tried or it should be evident from your question because members are expected to ask unique/very complex type of questions here. The questions, for which solution can be found by simple googling are depreciated here :)

Answer (score 0):

I have got my own answer.
I tried to work on query after told by **Mr. Sami**. Thanks to Mr. Sami. Here is my Query:

```
SELECT sID, eID,
    (SELECT SubjectName
      FROM  dbo.Subject
      WHERE (sID = dbo.tblSbjEmp.sID)) AS SubjectName
FROM dbo.tblSbjEmp
ORDER BY sID
```

This is a Correlated Subquery and updatable. Thanks to all.